# What is called singing with a song?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

When you sing with a song, for example, sing Wings of Birdy quietly or loudly by yourself when you are listening to it. What is the phrase of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the phrase you are referring to it **singing along**

Examples

I am singing along with the song

He is singing along with the song

They are singing along with the song.

I sang along with the song (past tense)
They sang along with the song